# How to create a user defined segment in a C program

Tags: c, stack

How to create a user defined segment in a C program apart from (Text,Data,Heap,Stack segment) which is created by gcc compiler by default. Assuming that it is Ubuntu linux X86 with gcc compiler.

Comment: Why do you want to do this?

Comment: At runtime, you might want to use [mmap(2)](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man2/mmap.2.html)